# Is using JavaScript for repetitive HTML bulks good?

Tags: javascript, html, client-side-scripting, server-side-scripting

Let's say you have a menu that's the same for all pages of a website. Should you use client-side or server-side scripting for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would generate it on the server side and cache it. Why make every browser do some work?

You can generate/output it with the same response for each page instead of having javascript make extra calls or cause the menu to only appear after the script finished running.

Comment: I don't understand what you would cache. The whole page?

Comment: @mwilcox - You can cache the HTML generated for the menu. The caching would happen on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If it's repetitive content, I would do client-side script loaded via `<script src=...>` so that the repetitive content is separately cacheable to reduce the amount your users have to download.  One caveat though, if your site has to work without javascript enabled, you obviously have to do it server-side.

With menus, you can also make the script deferred, so that it can download in parallel to the main content that your users came to the site to see.

Comment: This is fine for a web app, but not for a web site, because it will impair the SEO score.

Comment: @mwilcox, the question specifically says this is for menus.  The web page content should be in static HTML.  As long as the page link structure is navigable by some other means, and each page has the menu item text as its title, you lose nothing by making the menus dynamic.

Comment: It's not that it would break the search engine's ability to crawl the site. When you remove a key structure such as navigation from the visibility of the google-bot, the site will look completely different to it, and affect how the page is ranked. Menu+sitemap is better than just sitemap.